# Create a boundary to stop objects going under the Status Bar with pangesturerecognizer?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using pangesturerecognizer to move objects around the screen.

How would I create a boundary for the object to not go past a certain point at the top of the screen?
I'm thinking of using this `imageView.frame.origin.y > 0`but really unsure how to add it to this code.
The Status Bar is apparently covers 44pixels at the top of the screen and I'd proabaly like to do that to create a boundary of 44 at the bottom of the screen.

I'm using this code to do so:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                             recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);


        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

@SomeGuy Ok I tried to use :

```
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(MIN(recognizer.view.superview.frame.size.width - recognizer.view.frame.size.width / 2, MAX(-recognizer.view.frame.size.width / 2, recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x)),
                                             MIN(recognizer.view.superview.frame.size.height - recognizer.view.frame.size.height / 2, MAX(-recognizer.view.frame.size.height / 2, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)));
```

But I could not figure ou the logic to get it to stop from going under the bar. I did though get it to stop by doing this.

**EDIT**
this code stops it from going under the top bar but I'm not sure how to create a border or stop it from going to far below.

```
if (recognizer.view.center.y < 44) {


        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x ,
                                             44 + translation.y  );
    }
    else
    {
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x ,
                                             recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y  );
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this got -1, if your going to take marks away can you tell us why so I can learn from this.

Comment: I still don't understand why I got -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its simple enough, look into this picture:

[image]

in order to prevent your view from going out of the superview you must make sure that center of your view never gets a value in the red zone. For that you can use a code like this one:

```
float minX = recognizer.view.frame.size.width /2;
float maxX = recognizer.view.superview.frame.size.width - minX;
float minY = recognizer.view.frame.size.height /2;
float maxY = recognizer.view.superview.frame.size.height - minY;
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(MIN(MAX(minX,recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x),maxX),MIN(MAX(minY,recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y),maxY));
```

Comment: Thank you I got it to stay a custom distance by adding the amount I need to the minX and minY floats.  float minX = recognizer.view.frame.size.width /2 + 44;float minY = recognizer.view.frame.size.height /2 + 44;

Comment: Is that the right way to do that by adding the custom border values?

Comment: Is there a good book that explains the frames for gestures that you learnt this from?  I'm still trying to understand why you have divided the frame in 2

Comment: What is the size of the recognizer view ?

Comment: It's 320 x 480 for the iPhone 3/4.

Comment: well its just because your moving the view by its center and not its origin. Lets imagine your finger is at (0,100) position you affect that coordinates to the center, that means the center will be at x = 0 thats why half of your view gets out of the superview.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(MIN(recognizer.view.superview.frame.size.width - recognizer.view.frame.size.width / 2, MAX(-recognizer.view.frame.size.width / 2, recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x)),
                                             MIN(recognizer.view.superview.frame.size.height - recognizer.view.frame.size.height / 2, MAX(-recognizer.view.frame.size.height / 2, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)));
```

This will not let it outside the bounds of the superview, you'd need to add logic for any bars

Comment: The objects aren't going off the screen. They stop at 0 though I'd like to create a border or area that they can move within.